# NodeJs " Forward Secrecy" issues

Tags: node.js, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to get score A+ for my site www.cloudcaptcha.ga on ssllabs.com, but got this warning: 'This server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers. Grade capped to B'

I'm using NodeJs v12.6 with http2 server module. Generated valid dhparam using

> openssl dhparam -outform PEM -out dhparam.pem 2048

But it doesn't help.

My current server's secureContextOptions =

```
{
  ca: fs.readFileSync('chain.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem', 'utf8'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
  dhparam: fs.readFileSync('dhparam.pem', 'utf8'),
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  honorCipherOrder: false,
  allowHTTP1: true,
  ecdhCurve: 'auto',
}
```

How to fix this Forward Secrecy issue?

Comment: An article on configuring for perfect forward secrecy in node.js: [How to get A+ on the SSL Labs test in node.js](https://certsimple.com/blog/a-plus-node-js-ssl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with forward secrecy may be caused by the disabled `honorCipherOrder` option, try to enable it.

```
honorCipherOrder: true
```

When `honorCipherOrder` is disabled, the cipher suite negotiated during the handshake is selected according to the TLS client preference. There are TLS clients such as [IE 11 / Win Phone 8.1](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=IE&version=11&platform=Win%20Phone%208.1&key=65) that prefer non FS cipher suites over FS cipher suites.

In order to get `A+` it's also [required](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide#changes-in-2009e-21-january-2014) to add the [Strict-Transport-Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) (HSTS) header to every response with max-age of at least 6 months:

> New grade A+ is introduced for servers with exceptional
>   configurations. At the moment, this grade is awarded to servers with
>   good configuration, no warnings, and HTTP Strict Transport Security
>   support with a max-age of at least 6 months.

Example of an HSTS header with max-age set to 1 year:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
```

With native node.js response object you can set the header using [response.setHeader](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value):

```
response.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000");
```

If you use express you can also check [helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/hsts/) or just write a simple middleware that will add the header to every response.

Comment: Yes. It's help. I got 'A' score. Interesting, is it possible to get 'A+' ?

Comment: Yes, in order to get `A+` you should try to add `Strict-Transport-Security` header. I have updated the answer.